# JQ Array to new fields

Tags: json, jq

I have a sample json data like:

```
{
  "phone_number": "780-414-2085",
  "city": "Edmonton",
  "updated": "2015-10-19T00:03:10",
  "name": "Sir William Place ",
  "url": "http://www.bwalk.com/en-CA/Rent/Details/Alberta/Edmonton/Sir-William-Place",
  "last_visited": "2015-10-19T00:03:10",
  "rooms": [{
    "available": "Available",
    "bathrooms": ["1"],
    "suite_type": "1 Bedroom",
    "square_feet": ["594", "649"],
    "deposit": ["$499"],
    "price_range": ["$1059", "$1209"]
  }, {
    "available": "Available",
    "bathrooms": ["1"],
    "suite_type": "1 Bedroom + Den",
    "square_feet": ["771"],
    "deposit": ["$499"],
    "price_range": ["$1169", "$1249"]
  }, {
    "available": "Available",
    "bathrooms": ["1", "2"],
    "suite_type": "2 Bedroom",
    "square_feet": ["894", "970"],
    "deposit": ["$499"],
    "price_range": ["$1344", "$1494"]
  }, {
    "available": "Available",
    "bathrooms": ["2"],
    "deal": ["October FREE and $299 Security Deposit on 12 month leases "],
"suite_type": "2 Bedroom Bi-level",
"square_feet": ["894"],
"deposit": ["$499"],
"price_range": ["$1344", "$1394"]
  }, {
    "available": "Waiting List",
    "bathrooms": ["1"],
    "suite_type": "Bachelor",
    "square_feet": ["540"],
    "deposit": ["$499"],
    "price_range": ["$1004", "$1054"]
  }],
  "address": "8830-85 St., Edmonton, Alberta, T6C 3C3",
  "zip_code": "T6C 3C3"
}
```

And I am running a jq expression like:

```
'{phone_number, city, updated, name, address, zip_code, url, last_visited} + (.rooms[] | {suite_type, price_range_start: .price_range[0], price_range_end: .price_range[1]} + {available, square_foot_start:.square_feet[0], square_foot_end:.square_feet[1], deposit:.deposit[0], bathrooms:.bathrooms[0]})'
```

This gives me an ok output but repeats the same names because I just list the rooms array. I want to be able to set each item in the rooms array to something like room1, room2, room3 etc. But also to keep it in one entry, so for example with the sample here it ends up 5 entries because there is 5 rooms and name for instance gets repeated 5 times because the way I have it set now. I think I need to map the rooms to something but not sure how to do that.

Can someone advise on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what the expected output is and how it differs from the one you're getting. Can you provide a sample of what you would like the output to be?

Comment: Ok what I am looking for since this will be outputted to csv in the end is to take the rooms array and make cols for each item in the array so something like room0/available, room0/bathrroms, room0/suite_type, room0/square_feet,  room0/deposit, room0/price_start, room0/price_end, room1/available, room1/bathrooms etc like that so that would be the headers and then the value for each. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You'll probably find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33290267/3899165) useful.

Comment: Thanks Santiago, awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can update the elements in the array whilst keeping the other elements as is like this:

```
'.rooms[] |=  {suite_type, price_range_start: .price_range[0],
  price_range_end: .price_range[1]} + {available,
  square_foot_start:.square_feet[0], square_foot_end:.square_feet[1],
  deposit:.deposit[0], bathrooms:.bathrooms[0]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses functions.

```
def common_columns:
   "phone_number", "city", "updated", "name", "address", "zip_code", "url", "last_visited"
;
def common:
   .phone_number, .city, .updated, .name, .address, .zip_code, .url, .last_visited
;
def room_columns(n):
     range(n)
   | (
      "available_\(.)", "bathrooms_\(.)", "suite_type_\(.)",
      "square_feet_start_\(.)", "square_feet_end_\(.)", "deposit_\(.)",
      "price_range_start_\(.)", "price_range_end_\(.)"
     )
;
def rooms(n):
     . as $r
   | range(n)
   | $r.rooms[.]
   | (
       .available, .bathrooms[0], .suite_type,
       .square_feet[0,1], .deposit[0], .price_range[0,1]
     )
;

  [ common_columns, room_columns(6) ]
, [ common,         rooms(6) ]
| @csv
```

You can change the `6` to however many sets of room columns you need.