# How to use JQ to unroll a list of objects into denormalized objects?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON lines example:

```
{"toplevel_key": "top value 1", "list": [{"key1": "value 1", "key2": "value 2"},{"key1": "value 3", "key2": "value 4"}]}
{"toplevel_key": "top value 2", "list": [{"key1": "value 5", "key2": "value 6"}]}
```

I want convert it using JQ, unrolling the list to a fixed number of "columns", ending up with a list of flat JSON objects, with the following format:

```
{
    "top-level-key": "top value 1",
    "list_0_key1": "value 1",
    "list_0_key2": "value 2",
    "list_1_key1": "value 3",
    "list_1_key2": "value 4",
}
{
    "top-level-key": "top value 2",
    "list_0_key1": "value 4",
    "list_0_key2": "value 5",
    "list_1_key1": "",
    "list_1_key2": "",
}
```

<sub>Note: I actually want them one per line, formatted here for legibility.</sub>

The only way I was able to get the output I want was by writing out all the columns in my JQ expression:

```
$ cat example.jsonl | jq -c '{toplevel_key, list_0_key1: .list[0].key1, list_0_key2: .list[0].key2, list_1_key1: .list[1].key1, list_1_key2: .list[1].key2}'
```

This gets me the result that I want, but I have to write manually ALL the fixed "columns" (and in production it will be a lot more than that).

I know I could use a script to generate that JQ code, but I'm **NOT** interested in a solution like that -- it won't solve my problem, because this is for an application that accepts only JQ.

Is there a way to do it in pure JQ?

This is what I was able to get so far:

```
$ cat example.jsonl | jq -c '(.list | to_entries | map({("list_" + (.key | tostring)): .value})) | add'
{"list_0":{"key1":"value 1","key2":"value 2"},"list_1":{"key1":"value 3","key2":"value 4"}}
{"list_0":{"key1":"value 5","key2":"value 6"}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you know the names of the specific keys, Jeff's answer is great. Here's an answer that doesn't hardcode the specific key names, that is, it works with objects of any structure and levels of nesting:

```
[leaf_paths as $path | {
    "key": $path | map(tostring) | join("_"),
    "value": getpath($path)
}] | from_entries
```

An explanation: `paths` is a builtin function that outputs an array representing the position of each element of the input you pass to it, recursively: the elements in said array are the ordered key names and indexes that lead to the requested array element. `leaf_paths` is a version of it that only gets the paths to the "leaf" elements, that is, elements that do not contain other elements.

To clarify, given the input `[[1, 2]]`, `paths` will output `[0], [0, 0], [0, 1]` (that is, the paths to `[1, 2]`, `1` and `2`, respectively) while `leaf_paths` will only output `[0, 0], [0, 1]`.

That's the hardest part. After that, we get each of the paths as `$path` (of the form `["list", 1, "key2"]`) convert each of its elements to its string representation with `map(tostring)` (which gives us `["list", "1", "key2"]`) and `join` them with underscores. We keep this as the key of the "entry" in the object we want to create: as value, we get the value of the original object at the `$path` given.

Lastly, we use `from_entries` to turn an array of key-value pairs into a JSON object. This will give us an output similar to the one on Jeff's answer: that is, one in which only keys with values appear.

However, your original question requested values appearing on any of the input objects to appear in all of the outputs, with the corresponding values set to empty strings when missing on the input. Here's a jq program that does this: as Jeff says in his answer, you need to slurp (`-s`) all the input values for it to be possible:

```
(map(leaf_paths) | unique) as $paths |
map([$paths[] as $path | {
    "key": $path | map(tostring) | join("_"),
    "value": (getpath($path) // "")
}] | from_entries)[]
```

You'll notice that it's pretty similar to the first program: the main difference is that we get all unique paths in the slurped object as `$paths`, and for each object we go through those instead of going through the paths of that object. We also use the alternative operator (`//`) to set missing values to empty strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, dude, you've just blew me away! :)
I had stumbled on that paths function and thought it could help, but couldn't see how to fit the pieces.
Nice to know about that `//` operator, useful stuff!
Thank you!

Comment: Those paths... it's just so hard getting used to using them. Good one.  I'll have to work them into my repertoire.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can build that up:

```
{ "top-level-key": .toplevel_key } + ([
    range(.list|length) as $i
        | .list[$i]
        | to_entries[]
        | .key = "list_\($i)_\(.key)"
    ] | from_entries)
```

This will map for every corresponding list entry.

```
{
  "top-level-key": "top value 1",
  "list_0_key1": "value 1",
  "list_0_key2": "value 2",
  "list_1_key1": "value 3",
  "list_1_key2": "value 4"
}
{
  "top-level-key": "top value 2",
  "list_0_key1": "value 5",
  "list_0_key2": "value 6"
}
```

If you need to pad it out, you'll have to slurp up the results to determine how much is actually needed and add the padding.  But I'd leave it as this for now.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the toplevel_key with the list as a string on seperate lines you can use the following:

```
jq -r '"\(.toplevel_key) - " as $i | [.list | to_entries[] | "\(.value | .key1), \(.value | .key2)"] | join(", ") as $j | $i + $j' toplevel.json
```

This will provide the below result:

```
top value 1 - value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4
top value 2 - value 5, value 6
```